# Is there a way to avoid specific email domains in forms through jquery validate?

Tags: jquery, jquery-validate

I use jQuery Validate in my contact form which sends all data to a CRM (Zoho CRM) and I have received a lot of spam. It's very common some email domains like "mail.ru" (probably are temporary email addresses) and others, then, I would like to avoid spam in CRM by blocking those kind of stuff.

Is there some rule for jQuery Validate to mark an email field as invalid when user types some specific domains or addresses?

Comment: You can create any rule you wish.  See:  http://jqueryvalidation.org/jQuery.validator.addMethod/

Comment: BTW:  Most spammers are totally unaffected by your client-side validation routine because their software disables/bypasses JavaScript.    Instead, you'll need server-side validation, and then they'll probably just use domains that you allow.